# Spring Security - Custom filter Positioning (blank page after adding custom filter )

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, filter

Hi I have created a custom filter that filters the incoming IP. However the after the filter runs I get a blank page. No errors !. My filter is :

```
  public class IPFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain    arg2 )throws IOException, ServletException {

String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        if (ipAddress == null) {
               ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        }

 if(!ipAddress.equals(ValidatedIP))
        {
            logger.debug("The IP address is invalid");
            throw new BadCredentialsException("The IP address is not registered");
        }


    }

}
```

The debug view :

```
2016-12-14 16:02:18 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-14 16:02:18 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-12-14 16:02:18 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-14 16:02:18 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:192 - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@df877d
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:131 - Request 'GET /appointments/' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:131 - Request 'GET /appointments/' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /appointments/ at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'IPFilter'
       User's IP add                0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-14 16:02:46 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

During Normal processing without the custom filter the Debug list is :

```
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:171 - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:101 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@1e215c6. A new one will be created.
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1f6220e
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:131 - Request 'GET /resources/js/global.js' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:131 - Request 'GET /resources/js/global.js' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:100 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90541710: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 5F2FDA8C9019F2D6559984A169289A9F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /resources/js/global.js at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/resources/js/global.js'; against '/appointments/*'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/resources/js/global.js'; against '/schedule/*'
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:218 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /resources/js/global.js; Attributes: [ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:347 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90541710: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 5F2FDA8C9019F2D6559984A169289A9F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@1bcc1ed, returned: 1
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:242 - Authorization successful
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:255 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:309 - /resources/js/global.js reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher-servlet' processing GET request for [/spring-security/resources/js/global.js]
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:294 - Looking up handler method for path /resources/js/global.js
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:302 - Did not find handler method for [/resources/js/global.js]
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:168 - Matching patterns for request [/resources/js/global.js] are [/resources/**]
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:193 - URI Template variables for request [/resources/js/global.js] are {}
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:123 - Mapping [/resources/js/global.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@1755ea4]]] and 1 interceptor
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:947 - Last-Modified value for [/spring-security/resources/js/global.js] is: -1
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:337 - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper:211 - Skip invoking on
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher-servlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:997 - Successfully completed request
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:116 - Chain processed normally
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

These functions I see that are missing if I add the custom filter :

```
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper:211 - Skip invoking on
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1034 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher-servlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:997 - Successfully completed request
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:116 - Chain processed normally
2016-12-14 16:06:20 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Could anyone please guide me how to approach to solve the problem. Is it postioning of the filter ?. I am adding it after FORM_LOGIN_FILTER.

Note : Using Spring Security 4.0.2

-- Thanks

Comment: Your filter is flawed. When no exception is thrown, you stop the processing. Hence the request ends there. You need to call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` to continue processing. However why do you even need this filter? Spring Security has already support for that with expression, `hasIpAddress` should do the trick.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for the input ! .. It worked !